# Using libxslt with bundler and debian-packaged ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libraries

I am using `libxml-ruby` and `libxslt-ruby` within some of my projects. On the target systems I use `ruby 1.9.3p194` from the debian version 7.4. Bundler is installed via rubygems.

When I `require "xslt"` this happens:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/libxslt.rb:11:in `require': libxml_ruby.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/libxslt_ruby.so (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/libxslt.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/libxslt.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/xslt.rb:11:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/lib/xslt.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from test.rb:1:in `require'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The `test.rb`:

```
require 'xslt'
puts "passed"
```

The Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "libxml-ruby"
gem "libxslt-ruby"
```

The command is `bundle exec ruby test.rb` or `ruby test.rb` as the gems are installed into the system directory.

Passing `--path` to bundler behaves the same way.

I have set up the test project at https://github.com/krissi/test-xslt-require. For easy reproduction please use the (clean) vagrantbox `chef/debian-7.4` and follow this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/krissi/test-xslt-require
cd test-xslt-require
sudo ./install.sh
./run.sh
```

As a workaround one might set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `libxml-ruby/lib`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0/lib" ./run.sh
```

Am I missing something important on this? I thought about asking the maintainers about this problem, but I am really not sure who this might be: debian, rubygems, ruby, libxml, libxslt?

Long story short: I am grateful for any help or hints you may have.

Thanks in advance,
krissi

---

The output of `which ruby`:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

The output of `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

The output of `gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.7.2)
libxml-ruby (2.7.0)
libxslt-ruby (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Can you post command output command is : **which ruby** and **gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'**

Comment: Also let us know which gem version you are using.

Comment: Added the requested information

Comment: I force-updated rubygems on the system (which is generally not a good idea on production systems) to 2.4.1, but this also did not solve the problem.

Comment: I have changed the answer.Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

Its problem in libxslt-ruby binding. They have bind libxml support while building it.Hence relative path binding is not working.

2. --path:

It setup bundle installation on specified path.Its nothing to do with dynamic linking libraries.

3. To work with this "libxslt-ruby" you have to do following steps:

   ```
   ldd test-xslt-require-master/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/libxslt-ruby-1.1.1/libxslt_ruby.so
   ```

Above command output is as below:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7542a000)
    libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9 => /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9 (0x00007f23b5e58000)
    ***libxml_ruby.so => not found***
    libexslt.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0 (0x00007f23b5c42000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f23b5a05000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f23b569f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f23b52d8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f23b50ba000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f23b4eb2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f23b4cad000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f23b4a74000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f23b476e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f23b6496000)
    libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f23b44ee000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f23b42d5000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f23b40b3000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f23b3ead000)
```

You can check in about output "libxml_ruby.so" is not found.

4. Link the library using symbolic link:

   ```
   ln -s /home/rajesh/ruby/test-xslt-require-master/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/libxml-ruby-2.7.0/libxml_ruby.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   ```
5. Run command again using point number 3. It will show you the library is attached to libxslt module.
6. Add below code in your test.rb

   ```
       require 'rubygems'
       require 'bundler/setup'
       require 'xslt'
       puts "passed"
   ```
7. **rubygems** & **bundler/setup** will resolved dynamic linking library(LD_LIBRARY_PATH).
8. Try to implement **Nokogiri** modules.

[check this link](https://github.com/krissi/test-xslt-require/blob/master/test.rb) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification of the situation. After installation (using gem/bundler, not your manual way) the library resides in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0/lib`, which I described in the workarount above. the `--path` option of bundler does not help in this case either, because it does not generate a single directory with all `.so` files inside. The question is who is responsible to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar (which is obviously not done automatically in this case)